# Uploading a Content Management System Website to the internet

Tags: mysql, upload

Before I start I want to say this is my first site I am uploading that has a database - so I will appreshate any help whatsoever! 
What site is the best for webhosting - the cheapest and most reliable? I'm not sure how big my database will get - but I need to have a lot of space! (just in case). 
I, of cource, don't want my site to break down, so need a very reliable well known site. I have an account already with 1and1.com - and know about Godaddy.com but neither of them are really THAT cheap - if you know what I mean.  There is one site I found : "http://www.000webhost.com/" - does this seem alright?

Also, when I upload my site and database - do I have to leave my computer on full time to allow my database to be added to etc?!! Is there some way I can upload the database from my computer - so it's not anything to do with my computer ... or something.
As you can tell - this really is my first site - and I have really know idea.

Im using MYSQL, Coldfusion and Dreamweaver btw.

So again, any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap, Reliable, Easy.

In general, you can only pick two from the above.

Comment: ok, well I thin cheap and reliable are probably the best...:)

Comment: Cheap and Reliable = Google App Engine (http://code.google.com/appengine/). But you will have to adapt your application to Bigtable insteade of MySQL and to Python/Java. That's why it is not "easy" :) On the other hand, it will cost nothing while you are doing less than 5 million page views per month.

Comment: I'm not suggesting GAE for your needs. I was just trying to make a point that it is difficult to maximize Cheap, Reliable and Easy. Probably your best bet is to use a shared hosting service, like menkes suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check out bluehost.com.

No, you do not need to leave your computer on. You definitely want to put the database on their server, not yours. It sound like you need to do some research on that.

Comment: ok thanks. Ill give bluehost.com a look, and start some googleing.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the CMS files from your local system and then perform an export of your MySQL database (software like phpMyAdmin makes this dead simple) and then import it to your new database on your new host. Modify the configuration of your CMS (database host, username, and password will need to change) and check that it connects and reads the database properly and everything works right.

That way you don't need to leave your computer on all the time - you're literally moving your entire website to their server.

Comment: ok great! Ill create an account with a webhoster then i'll give it a try!